# Union between streaming and batch DataFrames/Datasets in StructuredStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to make union operation of streaming and batch dataframes. But i am catching the following **error:**

> ERROR Uncaught throwable from user code: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union between streaming and batch DataFrames/Datasets is not supported;;
>   Union

Is this feature is not supported yet in Struct Stream?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Could you elaborate on how you have used microbatch .. I am using ``foreachBatch`` and trying to do union but still getting same error message.

Comment: The only way you can make a union is from inside of micro-batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Union operation between a batch and a stream is not supported in spark structured streaming. To  see the list of unsupported operations you can check [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala)

Comment: Thanks. Any way union is possible inside of microbatch. That solved my problem

Comment: FYI A more readable list of unsupported operations is at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#unsupported-operations; but it doesn't mention `union` unfortunately.